# Parsing JSON array in Python to create a delimited string

Tags: python, json

Brand new to Python and trying to parse a JSON array like the one below:

```
[
  {"Event":"start","EventDateTime":"2015-09-15T03:45:16.681428Z"},
  {"Event":"process","EventDateTime":"2015-09-15T03:45:16.681428Z"},
  {"Event":"end","EventDateTime":"2015-09-15T03:45:16.681428Z"}
]
```

I need the output to be on string tab delimited fields and new line delimted row, like this:

```
start \t 2015-09-15T03:45:16.681428Z \n
process \t 2015-09-15T03:45:16.681428Z \n
end \t 2015-09-15T03:45:16.681428Z
```

here's the code I have so far:

```
          import json
      if not j or not i:
        return None
      try:
        arr = json.loads(j)
      except ValueError:
        return None
      if len(arr) <= 0:
        return None
      row=i
      for li in arr
        elem = json.loads(li, object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
        row=row + '\t' + elem.Key + '\t' + elem.Value + \n
      return row
```

First I get, Indent errors, fixed indents but getting error about 'collections' not defined.

Is there a way to do what I need without using that collections. When I remove the collections object I get other errors.

Thanks!!

Comment: Dude, seriously? 1. why dont you import collections? 2. what are "other errors"?

Comment: Did you read that I'm brand new to Python, Dude?

Comment: Imported collection and still get errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json    

j = """[
  {"Event":"start","EventDateTime":"2015-09-15T03:45:16.681428Z"},
  {"Event":"process","EventDateTime":"2015-09-15T03:45:16.681428Z"},
  {"Event":"end","EventDateTime":"2015-09-15T03:45:16.681428Z"}
]"""

j = json.loads(j)
for item in j:
    print '%s\t%s' % (item['Event'], item['EventDateTime'])
```

Comment: Thank you! But can this be done without referencing the names?

Comment: No, without names it wont be possible.

Comment: You can print without the field names, just change the print to: `print(' \t '.join(item.values()))` however, this doesn't guarantee the order of values so may print backwards.

Comment: Note: The OP had an OrderDict hook so this would work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like:

```
    j = '''[
{"Event":"start","EventDateTime":"2015-09-15T03:45:16.681428Z"},
    {"Event":"process","EventDateTime":"2015-09-15T03:45:16.681428Z"},
      {"Event":"end","EventDateTime":"2015-09-15T03:45:16.681428Z"}
      ]
      '''
import json
content = json.loads(j)
keys = content[0].keys()
for i in content:
    print(' \t '.join([i[k] for k in keys]) + '\n')
```

Comment: Thnaks!! can it be done without referencing the Names? I'd like to keep it generic if possible.

Comment: The solution above will not have a set column order which is the trade off for not hard coding the field names

Answer (score 1):

Given the OP is using an OrderedDict hook then you can do this reliable without referring to the names:

```
arr = json.loads(j, object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
for item in arr:
    print(' \t '.join(item.values()))
```